# In Dart, how do I add a ">>" before the input created by stdin.readLineSync()?

Tags: dart, command-line-interface, stdin

I'm writing a Dart console app for the first time and I've searched the Internet everywhere and can't find the proper answer.

In Python, the function `raw_input();` takes user input from stdin in a similar way to Dart's `stdin.readLineSync();`, *however* `raw_input();` takes a parameter: If I do something like `raw_input(">>");`, the CLI does something like:

```
>> _
```

In Dart, however, I cannot find a way to do something similar with `stdin.readLineSync();`, it simply outputs:

```
_
```

Is there a simple way for a new Dart user to accomplish this? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want:

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  stdout.write('>> ');
  var result = stdin.readLineSync();
  print(result);
}
```

`write` does not automatically add a newline.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to use the DCli package and its ask function:

```dart
var response  = ask('>>');
print(response);
```

The ask function provides a number of other options that help capturing data from the cli such as the functions 'confirm' and 'menu'.

https://onepub.dev/packages/dcli